# How to convert Persian (shamsi) date to Gregorian in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, date, date-conversion

I Use A lot data stored in Database to make a report and I was wondering if there is a **fast** way to convert all of the date in the tables to Persian date when selecting them.

there is some ways to convert but they **aren't SQL based** and so they are slower than a function just in the SQL.

so if any body knows how to do the converting in the SQL I will thank him a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And a day of searching I decided to do my own style of solving.

and the result is here: **Enjoy :D**

```sql
USE [Test]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[MyG2J]    Script Date: 10/11/2019 02:35:43 ب.ظ ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[MyG2J](@inputDate DateTime)
                                        RETURNS nvarchar(max)
                                        begin
declare @mDay int,@mMonth int,@mYear int,@sDay int,@sMonth int,@sYear int,@mid int, @isMC bit=0,@isSC bit=0,@preSC bit = 0;

set @mDay=day(@inputDate);
set @mMonth=MONTH(@inputDate);
set @mYear=YEAR(@inputDate);

if @mYear%4=0
    set @isMC=1;
else
    set @isMC=0;

set @sYear=@mYear-622;

if (@sYear+1)%4=0
    set @preSC = 1;
else
    set @preSC=0;

select @mid=
case
    when @mMonth=1 then'20'
    when @mMonth=2 then'19'
    when @mMonth=3 then'20'
    when @mMonth=4 then'20'
    when @mMonth=5 then'21'
    when @mMonth=6 then'21'
    when @mMonth=7 then'22'
    when @mMonth=8 then'22'
    when @mMonth=9 then'22'
    when @mMonth=10 then'22'
    when @mMonth=11 then'21'
    when @mMonth=12 then'21'
end


if @isMC=1
    begin
        set @mid=@mid-1 
    end

if @mMonth=3 and @mDay=@mid
    set @sMonth=@mMonth+9;
else
begin
    if (@mMonth=3 and @mDay>@mid) or (@mMonth>3)
        begin
            set @sYear=@sYear+1;
            set @sMonth=@mMonth-3;
        end
    else
        set @sMonth=@mMonth+9;
end

if (@sYear+1)%4=0
    set @isSC = 1;
else
    set @isSC=0;

if @isMC=1
    BEGIN
        if @isSC=0
            if @mMonth!=3
                set @mid=@mid+1
    END
else
    begin
        if @isSC=1
            if @mMonth!=3
                set @mid=@mid-1
    end

if @mDay>@mid
    begin
        set @sDay=@mDay-@mid;
        set @sMonth=@sMonth+1;
    end
else
    begin
        if @sMonth<7
            set @sDay=31+(@mDay-@mid);
        else
            begin
                if @sMonth=12
                    BEGIN
                        if @isSC=1
                            set @sDay=30+(@mDay-@mid); 
                        else
                            set @sDay=29+(@mDay-@mid); 
                    END
                else
                    set @sDay=30+(@mDay-@mid);
            end
    end



return Cast(@sYear as nvarchar)+'/'+Cast(@sMonth as nvarchar)+'/'+Cast(@sDay as nvarchar)
end
```

Comment: Tip: _Always_ specify a length for string data types. The default length depends on the usage: "When _n_ is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When _n_ is not specified with the CAST function, the default length is 30." [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks).

Comment: `@mid` is declared as an `int`, but you seem determined to assign a string value to it: `select @mid= case when @mMonth=1 then'20' ...`. The value `20` will work, there is no need to use the string `'20'` and force the database to convert it to an `int`.

Comment: `if @isSC=0 if @mMonth!=3 set @mid=@mid+1` is equivalent to `if @isSC = 0 and @mMonth != 3 set @mid += 1;`. You can also remove some of the `begin`/`end` blocks by using a single `select` statement to assign values to multiple variables rather than using several `set` statements. Though it may not improve clarity, you can combine `case` conditions, e.g. `when @mMonth in ( 1, 3, 4 ) then 20`.

Comment: Thanks for your tips and comments